# NSDateFormatter returning Null

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have this method on an object:

```
  - (NSString *)formattedScheduledOn
  {
      NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"];
      return [dateFormater stringFromDate:self.scheduledOn];
  }
```

scheduledOn is an NSDate object. Showing it as a raw date yields something like: 2013-03-22T09:44:28-07:00

But I always get null from that method. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The formatter is not correct for the string you provided.

Comment: Just tested your code by replacing `self.scheduledOn` with an `NSDate` instance and works just fine... How and when (in the VC lifecycle) are you calling your method?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your date is not `nil`.
Try the following code and see what you get in return

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
  [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"];
  return [dateFormater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

If change you passing the date as string then you should set the format according to the date string passed.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Comment: He is not passing a string. He is passing an `NSDate` object.

Comment: Yes you are right, as he mentioned the log output I thought it is String.

Comment: Though, I agree that probably his date object is `nil` at that point.

Comment: OK I see now. I definitely had the format wrong initially as I changed from CoreData to just showing it from JSON. I think the timezone offset is throwing it off though still with your format. The -07:00.

Comment: You can have a look at [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) It will help you more actually

Answer (score -1):

Why not do something like this?

Set your datePicker to pick or whatever you want.

```
[pick addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

-(IBAction)updateDateLabel:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:pick.date];
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked.